# rref vs. LU solving complexity

Tags: matlab

I was running a 'sanity test' today by comparing the run times of two elementary ways to solve Ax = b where A is square and b is a column vector:

```
    A = rand(1000,1000); b = rand(1000,1); Xmat = zeros(1000,1001);
    tic; [L,U] = lu(A);  x = U\(L\y); toc;
    tic; Xmat = rref([A b]); toc;
```

The output:

```
    Elapsed time is 0.018528 seconds.
    Elapsed time is 10.215791 seconds.
```

I find this discrepancy surprising, because for random, dense matrices I expect the LU step to be about as costly as Gaussian elimination (which in turn seems to be about as costly as finding the reduced echelon form of the augmented matrix, unless I'm missing something). I didn't expect LU to do so well for just a single vector b. The discrepancy also persists for more modest linear systems (say 100x100 matrices). What's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Gaussian elimination is not how LU is computed. Also LU is a "primitive" decomposition that is highly optimized in the Fortran LAPACK over decades. `rref` is computed at the matlab level by row swapping and pivoting. Moreover, `rref` checks the matrix entries and converts the entries into fractional representations if possible via `rats` function. That gives a huge overhead for `rref`. Because the only possible use case for `rref` is either educational or demonstration purposes. It is numerically not as reliable as LU decomposition.

That's the speed difference you are seeing.

Don't use `rref` if you are doing serious computations.

Comment: Of course, I'm aware of not using rref for any serious computations. I was just interested in the source of the discrepancy. But I am curious-- in what ways is LU "optimized" for a random, dense matrix according to the LAPACK?

Comment: @zeno Also added. Let me know if you need clarification